# how to access on button send, cancel in MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I want to set `isAccessibilityElement` to button send, cancel, delete draft, save draft but I cannot access to those button.
I have already tried:

```
mailComposer.navigationBar.topItem.isAccessibilityElement=YES;
```

and

```
mailComposer.navigationBar.topItem.rightBarButtonItem.isAccessibilityElement=YES;
```

Please help!

Answer (score 4):

You don't have access to Send and Cancel button of MFMailComposeViewController. These buttons and their action are pre-defined and are not meant to be changed.

From Apple Docs:

```
*Important: The mail composition interface itself is not customizable and must not be modified by your application. 
In addition, after presenting the interface, your application is not allowed to make further changes to the email content.*
```

Comment: Moreover, with iOS 6 and above, these buttons are not part of the view hierarchy; they are remote UI elements, drawn by another process entirely.